# getElementById within form tag

Tags: html, forms, input, tags, getelementbyid

I am trying to have an input box change to "th", "st", "nd" or "rd" depending on what number is entered in another box

My HTML is

```
<input id="hole_number" name="hole_number" maxlength="3" size="3" onkeydown="stndrdth()" onkeyup="stndrdth()" onkeypress="stndrdth()" onclick="stndrdth()" onfocus="stndrdth()" onchange="stndrdth()" />
<input id="stndrdth" name="stndrdth" size="2" maxlength="2" />
```

and my javascript is:

```
function stndrdth()
{
    var theinput = document.getElementById("hole_number").value;
    var righthandnumber = theinput.charAt(theinput.length-1);
    alert('hi');


    if( righthandnumber == 1 )
    {
        document.getElementById("stndrdth").value = '{$lang['st']}';
    }
    else if( righthandnumber == 2 )
    {
        document.getElementById("stndrdth").value = '{$lang['nd']}';
    }
    else if( righthandnumber == 3 )
    {
        document.getElementById("stndrdth").value = '{$lang['rd']}';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("stndrdth").value = '{$lang['th']}';
    }


}
```

and it works perfectly fine until I put the input boxes within a form tag:

```
<form method="get" ID="hole_form" action="./">
<input id="hole_number" name="hole_number" maxlength="3" size="3" onkeydown="stndrdth()" onkeyup="stndrdth()" onkeypress="stndrdth()" onclick="stndrdth()" onfocus="stndrdth()" onchange="stndrdth()" />
<input id="stndrdth" name="stndrdth" size="2" maxlength="2" />
</form>
```

Then the box is always empty

Can anyone please help?

Regards
Lee

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you provide some additional context as to what you are trying to do?  The name of your "stndrdth" element is rather... unconventional.  :)  What is the significance of "st", "nd", "rd" and "th"?  If you could recreate your sample at jsbin.com too, that would help enormously.

Comment: I'm using those letters so it will be 1st or 42nd or 23rd for example

Comment: Ah yes, thank you!  It seems so obvious now.  Perhaps a better id name would be "ordinal" instead of "stndrdth"?

Comment: is your function being called at all?  does it exist in the same scope as the input tag?  try putting an alert inside your function to see if it is being called in the first place.